# javac: target release 7 conflicts with default source release 1.8

Tags: java

I am playing with javac and I cant compile simple java class to 1.7 version.

```
C:\Tests>javac -target 7 GreetingsUniverse.java -nowarn
javac: target release 7 conflicts with default source release 1.8

C:\Tests>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_73
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

add a -source that matches your -target, so 1.7 I believe.  Should fix it.

Otherwise you are compiling all those cool 1.8 closures onto a 1.7 jar to run on a 1.7 jvm which is just not going to work.

Comment: It gave a warning but ran successfully for `javac -target 1.7 -source 1.7 newq.java`.

Comment: But then why do we call JAVA Write Once Run Anywhere if we cannot run code written in java 8 on a java 7 machine?

Comment: Write Once Run Anywhere means that you don't have to have a different set of code to run on different hardware (pc/mac/linux/...), but it doesn't mean you don't have to have the right JVM, the correct JVM is kind of the gasket that allows you to move the code without rewriting.  The reason  you can't work with an older JVM is each newer one adds features--you can't use those features and then expect an older JVM to somehow work--if everything worked in 7, they wouldn't bother making Java 8--they pretty much only upgrade the java # for breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that the `javac` program from a JDK release with version `1.n` can be run on a `java` program from release `1.n` or higher.

You are using `javac` from the JDK release `1.8.0_73` which means the compiled bytecode can be executed only by a JRE release `1.8` or higher.

Comment: That would make sense, if not for the fact it has a `-target` parameter; supposing `javac` is unable to generate bytecode for previous versions, why would it even have such a parameter?